# AVG antivirus removed adb.exe

Tags: android, sdk, adb

Avast antivirus in my system removed `adb.exe` from my `platform-tools` folder. I  searched SO for the same problem and came to a conclusion that Avast antivirus is an evil for Android studio.

The question is that how do I reinstalled the `adb.exe` again? Where is the `SDK` zipped file so that I can unzip it again for obtaining `adb` again?
Or will I have to download the whole `SDK` again?

Any positive comments will be appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can happen sometimes. I use Avast antivirus and it happened to me too. You just have to:

1. Right click on `Avast antivirus` icon, then click on `Virus Chest`

[image]

2. Right click on `adb.exe`, then click on `Restore and add to exclusions`

[image]

3. And it's done

Answer (score 3):

> will I have to download the whole SDK again?

No

> The question is that how do I reinstalled the adb.exe again?

Download `platform-tools` from [`official android site`](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools.html) (which include adb, fastboot, and systrace) extract it and paste it in your SDK folder (replace content if asked).

Comment: This is not what I want. I don't want to download the whole sdk again . Is there any alternate way?

Comment: if you click the link then you will see the link to download only platform tools , it's not whole SDK so download it and paste it under your SDK , replace content if asked , size of the file is around 10 MB

Comment: It is saying you don't have permission for platform tools.

Comment: who is saying ?

Comment: When I tried to add the adb into the platform tools folder it is asking for permissions

Comment: you can grant permissions to folder through properties => security , [try this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727008.aspx) , although i would suggest to apply the solution by @Ricardo Faria